# Match the column name based on the string in python?

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, match

I am new to python, I have an issue with matching the names of the column of Dataframe in python. So, I have a string `s = "8907*890a"` where a is the column name of a data frame. Now I want to match that with the column names of df which is there or not. I have tried it but the string is being taken as the whole. How to get only the 'a' from the whole string?

My code:

```
s = "8907*890a"

df=
      a  b  c
    0 rr 12 4
    1 rt 45 9
    2 ht 78 0
for col in df.columns:
    for i in s.split():
        print(i)
```

Which gives:

```
"8907*890a"
```

Expected out:

```
 a
```

Comment: Change `for i in s.split():` to `if col in s: print(col)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The split function accepts a delimiter as a parameter. By default the delimiter is a space. So when you try `s.split()` the interpreter is looking for a space in the string which it doesn't find in this case. So it returns the whole string as the output. If you try `s.split('*')` you will get

```
8907
890a
```

as output. In your case it appears that splitting the string is not the best option to extract the column name. I would go with extracting the last character instead. This can be done using `s[-1:]`